# Hide Image MAP and display Image MAP for new image

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, hide

I have searched for this a lot but could not find answer ...

(I searched in google 'How to hide image map area')

I am using

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

---

Link for image for which this Image map created

http://webvikas.net.in/befaft/images/index-03.png 
[image]

Image Maping....(for above image)

---

```
<map name="Map" id="Map1"  >


<area shape="rect" coords="28,134,225,324" href="#" id="printingservice.php" alt="Printing Service" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">


 <area shape="rect" coords="278,311,472,494" href="#" id='awardwork.php' alt="Award Works" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



<area shape="rect" coords="538,343,734,534" href="#" id='onsitestudio.php' alt="Onsite Studio" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



 <area shape="rect" coords="759,314,962,497" href="#" id='webservices.php' alt="Web Services" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



 <area shape="rect" coords="716,107,905,295" href="#" id='graphicdesigning.php' alt="Graphic Designing" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



 <area shape="rect" coords="505,142,694,324" href="#" id='artworkadaption.php' alt="Artwork Adaption" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



<area shape="rect" coords="246,102,447,286" href="#" id='imageediting.php' alt="Image Editing" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">



<area shape="rect" coords="67,337,255,524" href="#" id='printproduction.php' alt="Print Production" class="serviceclass" style="display:none">

</map>
```

---

When user click on 
    $('.serviceclass').click

i am displaying

http://webvikas.net.in/befaft/images/index-up-03.png
[image]
which is smaller one than previous one

Obviously i donot want (I want to hide) the earlier image MAP) or Image MAP created for this image and display new image MAP  for the smaller image

please help

I tried

```
<map name="Map" id="Map1" style="display:none">
```

does not work

Also tried

```
 $('.serviceclass').hide();
$('#Map1').hide();
```

Comment: can use one image map for both cases and just resize the image, map will adjust accordingly

Comment: I accept ....but if I have to resize it to its original size, Image map size does not grow to its original size....otherwise a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

This will make the image map resize with the image.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer